# Flex : How to right align cells in s:DataGrid?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have an s:DataGrid with 3 columns.  I'd like to right align the text in the last two columns but can't find a way to get it working.  I've tried creating a custom renderer and setting the textAlign to right, but it doesn't work.

Here's my custom renderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Label id="lblData" top="9" left="7" text="{data.outgoingCount}" fontWeight="bold" textAlign="right"/>
```

I would really like to know how to right align cells in the grid.  Thanks for anyone who can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to show text, take a look at the [DefaultGridItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/skins/spark/DefaultGridItemRenderer.html) class. If you don't specify an item renderer, this is what the Spark `DataGrid` will use.

`DefaultGridItemRenderer` has a `textAlign` style just like the `Label` does.

It's not readily apparent why your custom renderer is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The trick with right alignment using itemRenderers is to ensure that the itemRenderer either uses up the full width of the containing column OR is anchored to the right hand side of the grid column.  Otherwise, the text in the label right aligns to an itemRenderer like a label that is not on the right hand side of the grid.

So make sure that the component doing the item rendering has a width="100%" or has right=something.

Here is an example that anchors to the right side of the grid column.

```
<s:DataGrid>
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="Artist"  width="100"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="Price"  width="100">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>
                            <s:Label id="labelDisplay" textAlign="right" right="3" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle"/>
                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="Album"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <fx:Object>
                <fx:Artist>Pavement</fx:Artist>
                <fx:Price>11.99</fx:Price>
                <fx:Album>Slanted and Enchanted</fx:Album>
            </fx:Object>
            <fx:Object>
                <fx:Price>11.99</fx:Price>
                <fx:Artist>Pavement</fx:Artist>
                <fx:Album>Brighten the Corners</fx:Album>
            </fx:Object>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acknowledgments: I owe a lot to many posts in STACKOVERFLOW for this
Esp. [Number formatting in java to use Lakh format instead of million format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507658/number-formatting-in-java-to-use-lakh-format-instead-of-million-format)

In new Flex AIR application 1 good innovation I did **RIGHT ALIGN** + Indian comma separation

This is done by custom item rendering; need a lot of search and code effort
Adapted from Java but Java, C# & AS3 so similar it is a cakewalk porting

Outside of India nobody likes lakhs and crores; others happy with million billion
BUT we Indians think lakhs and dream crores; and find million(10 lakh) thora confushingh

Enroute I also did RIGHT ALIGN a very common need

**Flex Markup**

```
<s:GridColumn id="dmbtr" headerText="Amt (INR)" dataField="dmbtr" >
  <s:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
      <s:GridItemRenderer>
        <s:Label id="MyText" top="9" left="7" alpha="1"
                 text="{leftPad(data.dmbtr,10)}"
                 fontFamily="Lucida Console" textAlign="right"/>
      </s:GridItemRenderer>
    </fx:Component>
  </s:itemRenderer>
</s:GridColumn>
```

**AS3 Function**

```
public function leftPad(inp:Number,size:int):String {

  var lstr:String=Math.round(inp).toString();
```

// LAKHS CRORES Indian Style

```
  var pat3:RegExp = /(\d+)(\d{3})$/;
  lstr = lstr.replace(pat3, "$1,$2");

  var pat2:RegExp = /(\d+)(\d{2},.+)/;

  var pat1:RegExp = /\d{3,},.+/;

  while(lstr.match(pat1)) 
    lstr = lstr.replace(pat2, "$1,$2");
```

// RIGHT ALIGN part

```
  var strLen:int = lstr.length;
  var padLen:int = size - strLen;

  if (padLen <= 0) 
    return lstr;  

  var myspaces:String="                    ";  // 20 OK

  return myspaces.substring(0,padLen)+lstr;
```

}

The trick is to left pad and use fixed width font

My requirement was nearest rupee

If you need decimals(paise for INR) use toFixed method of Number
and change pat3 as 
var pat3:RegExp = /(\d+)(\d{3}.*)$/;

The right align part is after the Indian commas

Answer (score 0):

The best and simple way to do that:

```
<s:DataGrid>  
...  
    <s:columns>  
        <s:ArrayList>  
            <s:GridColumn id="col3" dataField="price" headerText="Price">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:DefaultGridItemRenderer textAlign="center" />
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:GridColumn>
            ...
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
...
</s:DataGrid>
```

Source: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/863955?tstart=0