# Number formatting in java to use Lakh format instead of million format

Tags: java, formatting

I have tried using `NumberFormat` and `DecimalFormat`. Even though I am using the `en-In` locale, the numbers are being formatted in Western formats. Is there any option to format a number in lakhs format instead?

Ex - I want `NumberFormatInstance.format(123456)` to give `1,23,456.00` instead of `123,456.00` (e.g., using the system described on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)).

Answer (score 10):

Since it is impossible with standard the Java formatters, I can offer a custom formatter

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(formatLakh(123456.00));
}

private static String formatLakh(double d) {
    String s = String.format(Locale.UK, "%1.2f", Math.abs(d));
    s = s.replaceAll("(.+)(...\\...)", "$1,$2");
    while (s.matches("\\d{3,},.+")) {
        s = s.replaceAll("(\\d+)(\\d{2},.+)", "$1,$2");
    }
    return d < 0 ? ("-" + s) : s;
}
```

output

```
1,23,456.00
```

Comment: What to do if I don't want decimal??

Answer (score 7):

While the standard Java number formatter can't handle this format, the [DecimalFormat class in ICU4J](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/DecimalFormat.html) can.

```
import com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat;

DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#,##,##0.00");
System.out.println(f.format(1234567));
// prints 12,34,567.00
```

Answer (score 2):

This kind of formatting is not possible to do with `DecimalFormat`. It only allows a fixed number of digits between the grouping separator.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

> The grouping size is a constant number of digits between the grouping
>   characters, such as 3 for 100,000,000 or 4 for 1,0000,0000. If you
>   supply a pattern with multiple grouping characters, the interval
>   between the last one and the end of the integer is the one that is
>   used. So "#,##,###,####" == "######,####" == "##,####,####".

If you want to get Lakhs format, you have to write some custom code.