# Formatting numbers in Java / Indian numbering system

Tags: java, string-formatting, decimalformat

I want to obtain number in following format:

```
1000   =    1,000
10000  =   10,000
100000 = 1,00,000
```

I tried this:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class StringProcessingDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     String pattern = "##,##,###.###";
        DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
        String output = myFormatter.format(2564484.125);            
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

But despite of pattern `##,##,###.###` I am getting output as `2,564,484.125` while I think I should get it as `25,64,484.125`. Why?

Comment: What format is `25,64,484.125`?

Comment: Why do you think the output is that?

Comment: @Tichodroma `25,64,484.125` is having comma separator at [lakh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh)'s place instead of million's place along with thousands place

Comment: But I dont see why that pattern does not produce what I want

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve your requirement with this

```
public static String format(double value) {
    if(value < 1000) {
        return format("###", value);
    } else {
        double hundreds = value % 1000;
        int other = (int) (value / 1000);
        return format(",##", other) + ',' + format("000", hundreds);
    }
}

private static String format(String pattern, Object value) {
    return new DecimalFormat(pattern).format(value);
}
```

Comment: yess but it trims the fractional part

Comment: `format(2564484.125)` prints `25,64,484`

Comment: nyways got the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14510951/1317018)

Answer (score 2):

> But despite of pattern ##,##,###.### I am getting output as 2,564,484.125 while I think I should get it as 25,64,484.125. Why?

You can supply multiple grouping characters, but only one is used. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

> If you supply a pattern with multiple grouping characters, the interval between the **last one and the end of the integer is the one that is used**.
>
> So "#,##,###,####" == "######,####" == "##,####,####"

It seems that formatting the Lakh format is not possible with standard Java mechanisms, see [Number formatting in java to use Lakh format instead of million format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507658/number-formatting-in-java-to-use-lakh-format-instead-of-million-format) for a solution.

Comment: ohh surprising that, but then unintutive, how I can achieve what I want then?

Answer (score -1):

This may be because of number format: million, billion, and trillion...... So, I have created a java function for your need:

```
String lakhFormattedComma(Double d) {
  String[] str = d.toString().split("\\.");
  int len = str[1].length();
  if (str[1].substring(len - 3, len - 1).equals("E-")) {
    return String.format("%." + (len - 3 + Integer.valueOf(str[1].substring(len - 1))) + "f", d);
  } else if (str[1].substring(len - 2, len - 1).equals("E")) {
    str = String.format("%." + (len - 2 - Integer.valueOf(str[1].substring(len - 1))) + "f", d).split("\\.");
  }
  String out = "." + str[1];
  len = str[0].length();
  if (len < 3) {
    return str[0] + out;
  }
  out = str[0].substring(len - 3) + out;
  for (int i = len - 5; i >= 0; i = i - 2) {
    out = str[0].substring(i, i + 2) + "," + out;
    if (i == 1) {
      out = str[0].substring(0, 1) + "," + out;
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```