# Unable to display Indian currency format(##,##,###.##) in <p:inputNumber/> control of primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I use a  control to get input as Indian currency. The format which I expect is `##,##,###.##`, but I'm not able to achieve this with both `locale='hi_IN'` or `pattern='##,##,###.##'`. The value of the control is of type double.

If I change locale to `'hi_IN'`, digits will be displayed in Devanagari with default thousand separator `format(#,###,###.##)`. 
Is there a way to achieve INR format?

Comment: Really interesting - so in `hi_IN` locale the `.` is a decimal separator, and the `,` are what? Hundreds of thousands separators?

Comment: Maybe java experts know how to generally treat this pattern in java - this is why I added the `java` tag.

Comment: Maybe I am missing it but p:inputNumber has properties for  decimalSeparator="," thousandSeparator="." see the showcase.  https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputNumber.xhtml

Comment: @Melloware the separator separates groups of size 3. The OP needs to separate mixed size groups 2 and 3. While wie say 2,500,000 is 2.5 Million they say it's 25 lakh (a friend explained to me). Knowing this term I found this QA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507658/number-formatting-in-java-to-use-lakh-format-instead-of-million-format   - looks like the op needs a custom converter as this is impossible using standard Java API.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this response to the pure Java variant of your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14511840/865107) I made up a converter using `com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat`:

```
package my.converter;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.ConverterException;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

import com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat;

@FacesConverter("enhancedDecimalConverter")
public class EnhancedDecimalConverter implements Converter<BigDecimal> {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (null == value) {
            return null;
        }

        DecimalFormat format = getFormatter();
        BigDecimal result;
        try {
            result = BigDecimal.valueOf(format.parse(value).doubleValue());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(e);
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, BigDecimal value) {
        if (null == value) {
            return null;
        }

        DecimalFormat format = getFormatter();
        String result = format.format(value);

        return result;
    }

    private DecimalFormat getFormatter() {
        return (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(getLocale());
    }

    private Locale getLocale() {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
    }
}
```

Usage in XHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:inputText value="#{myBean.decimalVal}"
            converter="enhancedDecimalConverter">
        </p:inputText>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="formatted: " />
            <h:outputText value="#{myBean.decimalVal}"
                converter="enhancedDecimalConverter">
            </h:outputText>

            <h:outputText value="raw: " />
            <h:outputText value="#{myBean.decimalVal}">
            </h:outputText>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton value="submit" process="@form" update="@form" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Example output screenshot:

[image]

Maven Dependency in `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
        <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
        <version>64.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Example `Locale` configuration in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>hi_IN</default-locale>
    </locale-config>
</application>
```

Beware the dependency introduced here is a 12 MByte `.jar` and it's licensed under [Unicode/ICU License](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unicode-org/icu/master/icu4c/LICENSE). Make sure this is compatible with your project if you use it.